# linux gpg command → php gnupg library interpretation

Tags: php, shell, encryption, gnupg, sign

I have a .sh code where I sign encrypt a .gz file with gpg command with user_ID. How can I get same output file from php library gnupg?

.sh code:

```
gpg -se -r ${GPG_USER} file.csv.gz
```

output:

```
file.csv.gz.gpg
```

Current attempt code PHP:

```
use gnupg;

$gpg = new gnupg();
$gpg->addencryptkey("FINGERPRINT"); //How to find FINGERPRINT?
$gpg->addsignkey("FINGERPRINT","USER_ID"); //How to find FINGERPRINT?
$enc = $gpg->encryptsign(file_get_contents("file.csv.gz"));
$file = fopen("file.csv.gz.gpg","w");
fputs($file, $enc); //is it correct way to export encrypted output file?
```